# Basis for the space of 2 by 3 matrices whose nullspace contains $(2,1,1)$

Tags: linear-algebra

To find a basis for the space of $2$ by $3$ matrices whose nullspace contains $(2,1,1)$

My attempt:

Let A=   \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b & c \\
        d & e & f \\
        \end{bmatrix}
Then $(2,1,1)$ is a solution to $Ax=0$

So I get,
$$2a+b+c=0$$
$$2d+e+f=0$$

How will I proceed further?

Comment: So, you have a system of two (homogeneous, linear) equations in six unknowns. Do you not know how to find a basis for the space of solutions of such a system?

Comment: yes..got it..thanks!

Comment: Good. Let me encourage you to write it up, and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Gram–Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to do this. For a certain $x_1$ and $x_2$ (such that $x$, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are linearly independent) you can get 
\begin{align}
y &=\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix}=x_1-x\cdot \frac{x\cdot x_1}{x \cdot x}, \\
z &=\begin{bmatrix}d \\ e \\ f\end{bmatrix}=x_2-x\cdot \frac{x\cdot x_1}{x \cdot x} -y\cdot \frac{y\cdot x_1}{y \cdot y}.
\end{align}
If you choose $x_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 6 & 0\end{bmatrix}^T$ and $x_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 30\end{bmatrix}^T$, you will end up with 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} y^T \\ z^T\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a & b & c \\ d & e & f\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 5 & -1 \\ -12 & 0 & 24\end{bmatrix}.
$$

In order to find a basis for the space of $2$ by $3$ matrices whose nullspace contains $\begin{bmatrix}2&1&1\end{bmatrix}$, I write the linear equations you mentioned in matrix format:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\\e\\f\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now let
$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix},
$$
then the solution to your problem is the nullspace of $B$. This can be easily found using the result above:
$$
\text{Null}(B) = \begin{bmatrix}-2 & -12 & 0 & 0 \\5 & 0 & 0 & 0\\-1 & 24 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & -2 & -12 \\ 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 24\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: What is the meaning of the $x_1$ and $x_2$ you have chosen? And how does this answer the question, which was not to find a single matrix with $(2,1,1)$ in its nullspace, but to find a basis for the vector space of all matrices with $(2,1,1)$ in the nullspace? (and as it happens, your matrix doesn't even have $(2,1,1)$ in its nullspace, so I'm even more puzzled as to how this is an answer to the question).

Comment: Good point! My answer is wrong in many ways...
So $x_1$ and $x_2$ can be arbitrarily chosen as long as $x$, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are linearly independent. 
"To find a basis for the vecot space of all matrices with $(2,1,1)$ in the nullspace" --> you are right, I read the question wrong.
You say that my matrix doesn't even have $(2,1,1)$ in its nullspace --> that is because of a type, is now fixed.

Comment: Good, it's correct now, though it seems to me to be a lot more work than is necessary.

Comment: In what sense, it is too much work? I good have written that the answer is $\text{Null}(B)$ and nothing more. But I also explained one way to come up with the Nullspace. If you know a faster way, then please let us know :)

Comment: Here's a much faster way: you just look at the equations $2a+b+c=0,2d+e+f=0$ and you see that $a,b,d,e$ can be assigned arbitrarily, and you write down the basis $(1,0,-2,0,0,0),(0,1,-1,0,0,0),(0,0,0,1,0,-2),(0,0,0,0,1,-1)$. If that's too ad hoc, well, your matrix $B$ is already in (nearly) reduced row-echelon form, and every Linear Algebra text tells you how to read off a basis for the nullspace of a matrix in that form. There's no need whatever to involve Gram-Schmidt in this.

Comment: That is much easier. I can see that my linear algebra class is a bit too long ago :p (or that my memory is failing). Thanks!

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry for asking questions to some comment 5 years ago, but if I choose to set variables to $(\frac{a+b}{-2}, a, b)$, I would get a different set of basis as $(-1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0), (-1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, -1, 2, 0), (0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 2)$. Is there anything incorrect in this attempt?

Comment: @Uduru, I don't know what you mean by "set variables to $({a+b\over-2},a,b)$", but in any case if you have a new question it's best to post it as a new question.